# converting tensorflow transpose to pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

What is the equivalent function of

```
x = tf.transpose(y, perm=[2, 0, 1])
```

in `pytorch`?
For instance, If I have

```
import torch
y=torch.randn(10, 480, 640)
```

How can I convert `y` to `x` in `pytorch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.permute.html?highlight=torch%20permute#torch.Tensor.permute):

```
>>> x = y.permute(2, 0, 1)
```